# Quickfix & Preview window resizing

Tags: vim

Normally when quickfix window opens it changes the screen layout, but Vim restores
it when that window is closed.

But there is a situation where the layout restoration fails: when the
preview window is open, vertical splits are presents and `:wincmd J` is executed
in quickfix (or it is opened with `:botright copen`). In this case the size of
preview window is changed.

I came with a solution which I placed on ~/.vim/ftplugin/qf.vim,

```
  " Only do this when not done yet for this buffer
  if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
     finish
  endif

  " expand quickfix when there are vertical splits
  wincmd J

  func! RestorePreviewWindow()
     let l:quickfixHeight = winheight(0)
     wincmd p " include previous window on jump list
     silent! wincmd P  " jump to preview window
     if &previewwindow " if we really get there...
        exe "resize " . (&previewheight - l:quickfixHeight - 1)
        wincmd p " back to old window
     endif
  endfunc
  augroup quickfixClosing
     au!
     au BufDelete <buffer> call RestorePreviewWindow()
  augroup END
```

, but I was wondering if there is some better/simpler solutions to this
problem.

Comment: didn't know about `wincmd P`, that's useful.  I really like the idea of the preview window but the different resizing behaviour makes it hard to use - I work in tmux and frequently zoom the panes.  using `<C-w>=` sorts out normal windows but doesn't effect the special ones.  Might be able to use this to improve that!  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can reproduce the problem in plain vanilla Vim (`vim -N -u NONE`), I'd report it to the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php) to have it fixed inside Vim. The preview window should not change its size when other, normal windows could stand in for it.

If this is just a peculiarity of your setup, I think your implemented workaround is fine; I would probably solve it along the same lines.

Comment: It also happens on vanilla Vim, so I'll report it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was with this problem and I've tried your proposed qf.vim but it didn't work. I found something that did, in the qf help page, =|, so put this in your .vimrc:

```
au FileType qf botright cwindow
```

Comment: Indeed, I've switched to `botright cw` on most cases one year after asking this question, but I didn't think of including it here -- thank you! I had very few problems using the workaround on the question, which ceased when the use of `wincmd J` were reduced.

Answer (score 0):

I used your answer to improve the default auto resize behaviour of vim.

It's not really an answer to this question but hopefully other people might find it useful as I stumbled across this question for that reason:

```
nmap <silent> <C-w>= :call ResizeAllWindows()<cr>

function! ResizeAllWindows()
  call RestorePreviewWindowHeight()
  wincmd = "set all equal after restore
endfunction

function! RestorePreviewWindowHeight()
  silent! wincmd P "jump to preview, but don't show error
  if &previewwindow
    exec "resize" &previewheight
    wincmd p "jump back
  endif
endfunction
```